# MySQL Query to list multi-category articles by a specific category, while still retrieving primary cat

Tags: mysql, categories

I have a article system where articles that can be in different sections such as recipes, howto, editorial, news, etc.

Each of these articles can also belong to a single or multiple categories. For example, a recipe can be in the muffin category and the blueberry category.

Then when I generate the url, it would be in the format of:

```
example.com/{post_section}/{primary_post_category_slug}/{post_title}/
```

When listing the articles, above the title I show each category that the article is part of. Each of these categories are a link that when clicked on show only the articles that are part of that category.

My problem is that when listing all the articles in a category, if an article has multiple categories, I can't figure out how to retrieve the primary one.  For example, if I have an article that is a recipe for blueberry muffins I would put it in the primary category of muffins and a secondary category of blueberry.

Now if a visitor browses the blueberry category, it should list all articles related to blueberrys, but the link should still contain whatever the primary category slug is. My problem is retrieving the primary category when it is different than the category we are listing.

Below is the example query I am using and the table structure:

```
select p.*, c.*, t.* from posts p 
  left join post_category_selected a on a.post_id = p.post_id
  left join post_category c using (post_category_id)
  left join post_section t using (post_section_id)
    and c.post_category_slug = "blueberry"
    and t.post_section_slug = "recipes"
  order by p.post_publish_date desc
```

This does return all articles that have the blueberry category, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the primary_category of muffins so I can use it when I generate my link.

Hope this makes sense.

**Table structure:**

```
posts
 |- post_id
 |- post_title
 |- post_section
 |- post_slug
 |- post_publish_date

post_category
 |- post_category_id
 |- post_section_id
 |- post_category
 |- post_category_slug

post_category_selected
 |- post_category_selected_id
 |- post_id
 |- post_category_id
 |- is_primary (enum Y,N)

post_section
 |- post_section_id
 |- post_section_title
 |- post_section_slug
```

Comment: What is post_type table and how is it different from the categories?

Comment: Sorry about that. When i copied my tables I was trying to make it clearer what each thing was and forgot to change a few things. Its all fixed in the original post now. Thx

Comment: Are you sure that you should determine the primary category with a sql query? To me it seems that the primary category is tied to a particular post, not to a category. I mean, in the blueberry list you would have recepies not just for muffins, but for other types of food as well. So, I would preserve the primary category of the previous post by using either session or by encoding it into the url.

Comment: The primary category is tied to the post via the post_category_select association table.  It would find the list of posts associated with the blueberry category by checking the association table.

I am not sure what you what you mean by preserving the category. This article would appear in a list, each with their own different categories. When someone clicks on the blueberry category link it shows a list of articles associated with that category. Not sure how it would indicate what the primary is.

Comment: That's exactly my point: no category listing can indicate any primary category because the concept of primary category applies to posts only. So, there is no way to get the primary category based on a pure category related search. This is why I suggest you to preserve the primary category of any posts that a given user opens. Use cookies, or sessions, or encode it in the link that will open the category listing. This way you can retrieve the primary category outside of the query in your above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to post_category and post_category_selected twice each, once for the selected category and once for the primary category.  Like this:

```
select p.*, c1.*, t.*, 
c2.post_category_slug as primary_category_slug 
from posts p 
  left join post_category_selected a1 on a1.post_id = p.post_id
  left join post_category c1 using (post_category_id)
  left join post_section t using (post_section_id)
    and c.post_category_slug = "blueberry"
      and t.post_section_slug = "recipes"
  left join post_category_selected a2 on a2.post_id = p.post_id
    and a2.is_primary = 'Y' 
  left join post_category c2 on c2.post_category_id = a2.post_category_id
  order by p.post_publish_date desc
```

You might need to add some additional columns from c2, depending on your other requirements.

Comment: Thanks!  Never thought of joining the two tables again. Appreciate the help. It work great.